# Dynamically adding ng-model to input boxes attribute using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to dynamically add ng-model to input boxes attribute using jquery. 
I want to do this because i have over 10 input boxes, so i only want to use one.
So what i have done is have many check boxes and when i check on a specific one a input boxes will slide down.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepickerFr" ).datepicker();
    $( "#datepickerTo" ).datepicker();
    $('#dateInput').slideUp();
    $('#textInput').slideUp();
    var optionC = [];
    $('[name="searchOption"]').each(function(i, obj) {
        $(this).click(function() {
            var textSearch = $(this).parent().text();
            var e_name = $(this).attr('id');
            var lastName = e_name.substring(e_name.length - 4, e_name.length);
            if (lastName == "Date") {
                $('#searchLabelD').html(textSearch + "   Pick a date ( Month | Day | Year )");
                $('#datepickerFr').attr('ng-model', e_name + 'Fr');
                $('#datepickerTo').attr('ng-model', e_name + 'To');
                $('#dateInput').slideDown();
                $('#textInput').slideUp();
            } else {
                $('#inputSearch').attr('ng-model', "search." + e_name);
                $('#searchLabelT').html(textSearch);
                $('#dateInput').slideUp();
                $('#textInput').slideDown();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

So far when i look at the inspector element i see that ng-model attribute is there but it doesnt seem to be doing anything.

Comment: May be because your particular piece of angular code which is using ng-model is running before jquery could finish with ng-model insertion.

Comment: Yes thats the problem, because everytime i click on a new checkbox jquery will automatically add a new ng-model after page load so angular doesnt know whats is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Why not assign the ng-model to empty $scope variables, and only fill the one you want to fill instead of trying to add ng-model. The reason why this isn't working is like AngularHarsh said, because your angular code is allready applied when you are adding ng-model with jquery

Comment: Hi Guinn the only reason i did that is because, the attribute of my ng-model must be bind to search field. And i have many search field. So for example: search.name, search.company ..... search.cost are used with ng-repeat so that i can search for data in the right field. The .name .company ...... .cost is gathered from check-box id=name, id=company, id=cost. But how do i integrate empty scope variable and bind it to ng-repeat and filter it

Comment: This sounds like a very unpractical approach, but it isn't really clear to me what you mean then. If you want to put the value of .name etc in some kind of array when a check-box is checked, you could put an ng-change on the checkbox with a function that assigns the values

Comment: If you could put what you have in a fiddle of plunker, maybe things get a little more clear.

Comment: My code is rather messi and large Guinn. Well that settles it, is unpractical so i am going to try a different approach. Thank you